# Electron scattering on nucleus, form factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, scattering

I am currently studying the scattering of an electron on a nucleus... In my book it says that the form factor can be measured in electron scattering experiments and is given by : $F(q^2)=\frac{d\sigma _{exp}}{d\sigma _{point}}$, where $F$ is the form factor of the nucleus and $d\sigma$ is the differential cross section... But isn't this derived from : $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}_{point-like} |F(q^2)|^2$ and the form factor should be squared in the first equation ? **Am I missing something** or is there and error in the book. I have checked a few books and have found the first expression as well as the other, which one is correct ?